# Why am I having the following errors compiling my java command line app?

Tags: java, compiler-errors

I have this program:

```
package com.example.java

public class Main{
    
    public static void main(String[] args){
        
        for(i=0; i<args.length; i++){
            System.out.println("This is index " + i + "==> " + args[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

I have saved the java file in the directory:

```
C:\Users\tonny\clsandbox>
```

The first time I have compiled it with the command line:

```
PS C:\Users\tonny\clsandbox> javac Main.java
```

And landed to this error:

```
Main.java:1: error: ';' expected
package com.example.java
                        ^
1 error
```

Then thinking I am resolving that, I used this other command line instead:

```
PS C:\Users\tonny\clsandbox> javac com.example.java.Main.java
```

And landed into this other error:

```
error: file not found: com.example.java.Main.java
Usage: javac <options> <source files>
use --help for a list of possible options
```

Pleas help me out. I am joining the Java community.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: The first error message should be very clear. You're missing a semicolon `;` and the compiler even tells you where in your source file. Next time please actually *read* the error message (because right now it feels like you didn't).

Comment: package com.example.java add tailing ;

Answer (score 1):

When we add the `;` at the end of the first line we get an error `i` is not declared so we add `int` in the for loop.

```
package com.example.java;

public class Main{

    public static void main(String[] args){

        for(int i=0; i<args.length; i++){
            System.out.println("This is index " + i + "==> " + args[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

We can now compile.

Answer (score -1):

The program wants to be in a folder structure that agrees with the package statement. So Main.java wants to be in a folder like .../foo/com/example/java/Main.java

From folder foo/ use: javac com/example/java/Main.java

To run from folder foo/ use: java -cp . com.example.java.Main

There will be a Main.class file in com/example/java/, but do not include the ".class" in the name.

Comment: I got you. So if I use the package statement in the code even the directory structure should agree? And one last question is package declaration necessary? is it a must? What is its use? When can I use it and when can I leave it, if it is optional?

Comment: yes, package statement and location of source file in directory must agree. package declaration is optional but strongly recommended. if omitted and java source file is in current folder then javac Main.java will work.

Answer (score -1):

correct written like this below
package com.example.java;
you lost symbol that ; at end of package statement.

Comment: Thank you it has worked. But does it mean I should not include the package when compiling even though I have declared it in the code? Because it has given me the file not found error when I first included the package in the javac command, and after removing it worked. Yesterday I was running another app in a command line, that I had coded and compiled with Intelij, I encountered error, after a bit of googling I read somewhere that I should include the package name when running the app in the command line. So I am asking, do we include the package name only when running and not when compiling?

Comment: @AntonyMukuha exactly. The compiler expects a file (so no package names, only file name preceded, if needed, by its path). The jvm expects a class name (including its package).